# MS Exchange noderunner very high RAM usage

Tags: performance, exchange, windows-server-2012, memory-usage

I've installed Windows Server 2012 and MS Exchange on a VMWare that has 4 GB of RAM and can use 2 cores of CPU (1.8 GHz each) for a school project. The server ran fine *before* the Exchange install, but after that the RAM usage is always around 92% or more, the most is used by **noderunner** task. I tried shutting the **Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller service** down from the services but nothing changed. Is there a way to shut that memory consuming process? I can't wait for multiple days for it to do whatever it wants, time is of the essence. 
EDIT: another one is IIS Worker process that takes up a lot of memory. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you even have any mailboxes with data in them?

Comment: Nope, just installed Exchange. EDIT: I have to make the server a mailbox though. I just need some users for that, I plan to add them asap.

Comment: Hmmm....memory seems a bit small for an exchange server.   Heck my laptop running win 7 enterprise consistently uses more about 6GB of memory.  I suspect that the system is hung swapping.

Comment: Eh, I got an answer like this. Guess I won't be using this solution. What about Zimbra and Zafara or Open-Exchange? on a win server 2012

Comment: This is a school project. That means your learning. That's good. One important thing to learn is to check the system requirements for the operating systems, applications and components that you're installing.

Comment: It wan't my choice to use Exchange, I have to. And I'm not learning, I'm expected to know all along with the other 8 subjects :(

Answer (score 0):

4 GB is too small for Exchange, except in CAS only installations. Since you have noderunner active, that means you have the mailbox role installed, and the minimum for a combined roles server is 8 GB.

Add more RAM or remove Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I think I'm in a bit of trap here. I have to use Exchange but my laptop's memory is 8GB only. Guess the one who came up with this as a somework knows little about servers. 
Is there a way to surpass this?